# Is it possible to scaffold all CRUD views for all models automatically without Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, dapper, scaffolding

It is possible to generate all of the CRUD views and controller for a specific model automatically, with Entity Framework. I'm using Dapper for all of my projects, and I do use a generator I created for generating model classes, metadata, and annotations. This works as intended for the most part.

But with Entity Framework, MVC has an option to generate all views for CRUD operations for a specific model. But this is impossible for my Dapper based models.

So, can I generate CRUD views for all of my models in some way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general Yes/no questions are not a good thing unless you want a yes/no answer. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The long answer is to write your own vsix extension to add a menu item. The shorter, easier but not as magical is a T4 template with manual file changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!